# How to get rid of blue highlight with astuetz sliding tab strip?

Tags: java, android, tabs, strip, sliding

I am using an astuetz sliding tab strip in my android application, and I cannot seem to figure out how to get rid of the blue highlight that appears when you are selecting a tab. I have provided a picture below to illustrate the problem. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That library uses this [drawable](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip/blob/master/library/res/drawable/background_tab.xml) as a background:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/background_tab_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/background_tab_pressed"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>

</selector>
```

where the [color](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip/blob/master/library/res/values/colors.xml) is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="background_tab_pressed">#6633B5E5</color>
</resources>
```

So you can create your own `selector` with your favorite color.